# Sending a request via proxy doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, python-3.5, http-proxy

I need to send a `http` request with `requests` in python. Proxy need to be in US so i get american currency.
So far i did this:

```
import requests
proxies = {'httpс': 'httpс://97.77.104.22:3128'}

response = requests.get("https://www.ncl.com/ca/en/search_vacations?cruise=1&cruiseTour=1&cruiseHotel=1&cruiseHotelAir=1&flyCruise=1&numberOfGuests=4294953449&state=undefined&pageSize=10&currentPage=", proxies=proxies)
cruise_results = response.json()
for line in cruise_results['results']:
    print(line)
```

Tried with several different IP/Port combinations but i still get the EUR prices. Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`proxies` dictionary](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies) should have `http` and `https` keys. **Not** `httpc`

```
import requests
proxies = {'https': 'httpс://97.77.104.22:3128'}

response = requests.get("https://www.ncl.com/ca/en/search_vacations?cruise=1&cruiseTour=1&cruiseHotel=1&cruiseHotelAir=1&flyCruise=1&numberOfGuests=4294953449&state=undefined&pageSize=10&currentPage=", proxies=proxies)
```

Comment: happens to everyone :)